# Start activity in onstop() method without showing it on the screen in the background until user re-open app

Tags: java, android

I want to start an activity in the `onStop()` method without the activity being loaded popping up on the screen which will disturb the user, I want it to just load the activity with the `onstop()` method in the background so that when user return to the app later on, user could see the activity being loaded, is there any way to make this possible?

I have read so many of the answers about this matter and tried `LifeCycleObserver` but the intent still pop up, I want it to stay in the background until user open the app again. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

in `your_Application` class create variable:

```
Boolean stateOn = false;
```

in your `onStop()` set value true,
like

```
MyApplication.stateOn = true;
```

in `onDestroy()` make it false again, (before calling `super.onDestroy()`)

```
MyApplication.stateOn = false;
```

and in on `onResume()` check it, *if it was true* , **start another activity**

```
if (MyApplication.stateOn) {
    startActivity({intent});
}
```

you can crate `your_AppCompatActivity` class and do above code in there, to appling this config in all activities who extends `your_AppCompatActivity`

Comment: of course it wll not work if the whole process would be killed when app is in background and you would back to it (which is pretty normal case on Android OS)...

Comment: Hi, I created a variable in Application class which is the main activity but I can't call it "MainActivity.stateOn' like this?

Comment: are you create customApplication extends Application ?
make stateOn  static

Comment: @Selvin i think he/she want start another activity just when app start from background, he/she can set values in sharedPrefernces simply on other way

Comment: Hi, is the Myapplication equals to MainActivity or a new java class in MainActivity?